# Laravel route and optional params

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have some problems with my controller in laravel 5.4

My routes.php:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{subdomain}.site.com','as'=>'www::','middleware'=>array('web','varnish')), function() {

   Route::any('/material/{page?}/', [
      'as' => 'www_material', 'uses' => 'www\MaterialController@index'
   ]);

});
```

My controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers\www;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use View;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MaterialController extends Controller {

    public function index($subdomain, $page = 1, Request $request)
    {
        echo $subdomain;
        echo $page;
       //...some code
    }
}
```

There is no problems with url `www.site.com/material/2/`:

```
submodain = www,
page = 2
```

But `www.site.com/material/`:

```
Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\www\MaterialController::index(), 2 passed and exactly 3 expected
```

I cant understand why this happend, because default value of page is 1.

Can someone help me? I cant solve this problem alone.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the order the arguments are in the index method.

As the Request object will always be present put that first followed by $subdomain and then $page

As stated on the [php website](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) above example #5:

> Note that when using default arguments, any defaults should be on the right side of any non-default arguments; otherwise, things will not work as expected.

```
public function index(Request $request, $subdomain, $page = 1)
{
    echo $subdomain;
    echo $page;
   //...some code
}
```

Comment: as per the PHP docs http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php (example #5) on order of default arguments: 'any defaults should be on the right side of any non-default arguments; otherwise, things will not work as expected'

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove trailing slash next to {page?} mentioned below and rerun the code.

```
Route::any('/material/{page?}', [
  'as' => 'www_material', 'uses' => 'www\MaterialController@index'
```

]);

Comment: This shouldn't make any difference as the .htaccess file shipped with Laravel accounts for this.